# BitBucket pipeline docker cache with git clone

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Why in BitBucket pipelines docker cache not working with git clone?
I have the next steps:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - git clone git@bitbucket.org:something/something.git
            - docker build .
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
```

In Dockerfile I have

> COPY something something

and everything before COPY is going from cache, but COPY and everything later is building all over again.

I already tried to move git clone to another step:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Clone repository
          script:
            - git clone git@bitbucket.org:something/something.git
          artifacts:
            - something/**
      - step:
          name: Build Docker image
          script:
            - docker build .
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
```

But the effect is still the same.